"learn science" or "learn about science"?
I saw both "learn science" and "learn about science" be used in many sample sentences. Are there any nuances between them, or they are both commonly used and interchangeable?

If you've seen lots of examples of both... then you've go your answer.

But what I wanted to ask is if there are any differences between them @JamesK

You coudl provide us with examples of the phrases in context.

In many contexts there is a subtle difference. As an example, She learned Japanese means that she became proficient in speaking understanding, reading, and writing the language. But She learned about Japanese does not; it means she acquired knowledge concerning the history, grammar, vocabulary, or other properties of the language.
One learns about art by studying its functions, history, media, cultural impact, major figures, and the like. I suppose that children can learn some things about art by painting—things like what it feels like to hold a brush and spread paint on some surface. But principally, the activity of painting enhances one’s ability in this medium of self-expression, so when one does so, one is learning art [no about].

So, as I deduce from your answer, "learn something" is like learning a subject to be better at some specific areas of that subject. "Learn about something" means exploring it more comprehensively. But in many contexts they are pretty much the same, right?

Almost. I think I would word the distinction in terms of enhancing one’s ability (e.g., learn poker) vice increasing one’s knowledge (e.g., learn about poker). As a further example, to learn about drug abuse is to become aware of its existence, causes, impacts, and the like, whereas to learn drug abuse [not a particularly idiomatic usage] would mean to develop the habit, become addicted, etc.

And learn about doesn’t imply comprehensiveness. A six-year-old could come home from school and report, “Today we learned about the immune system.” That would suggest that they learned that human’s have an immune system, what it's for, and things like that.  By contrast, a student in medical school would never say, “I’m learning about the immune system.” Learning it, yes—especially in preparation for an exam—or studying it, if it’s the topic of their research program.

Ohh, I think I got what you meant. Thank you for your explicit explanation.

Oxford's Learner Dictionary shows both learn something and learn about something in the same entry for learn and also gives several examples, to quote:

The children learn about art by painting.
She's very keen to learn about Japanese culture.

Without "about", the meanings are still the same. So yes, as far as I can tell they're interchangeable.
